# How do I populate the next empty cell with textbox data in excel using vb.net?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am nowhere short of an experienced coder and I'm really struggling with some coursework that is due at the end of Easter. I've tried using a do while loop and an index to try and check each available cell in the "A" column of excel - but when I run my code the program overwrites all the data previously saved in the spreadsheet and writes these values to cell "A2 - F2". If someone could explain to me exactly what I'm doing wrong and how to overcome this in really simple terms that would honestly be amazing.

Here's a copy of my code so far:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms


    Private Sub btnClientSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCSave.Click
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet As Object
        Dim index As Integer


        Dim filename As String = Application.StartupPath & "\spreadsheet"

        oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")
        oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add

        oSheet = oBook.worksheets(1)

        oSheet.range("A1").value = "Forename"
        oSheet.range("B1").value = "Surname"
        oSheet.range("C1").value = "DOB"
        oSheet.range("D1").value = "Phone number"
        oSheet.range("E1").value = "Email"
        oSheet.range("F1").value = "Address"
        oSheet.range("A1:B1:C1:D1:E1:F1").font.bold = True

        index = 1
        Do While oSheet.range("A" & index).value <> ""
            index = index + 1
        Loop

        If oSheet.range("A" & index).value = "" Then
            oSheet.range("A" & index).value = txtCForename.Text
            oSheet.range("B" & index).value = txtCSurname.Text
            oSheet.range("C" & index).value = txtCDOB.Text
            oSheet.range("D" & index).value = txtCNumber.Text
            oSheet.range("E" & index).value = txtCEmail.Text
            oSheet.range("F" & index).value = txtCAddress.Text
        End If
        oBook.saveas(filename)
        oExcel.quit




    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if workbook already exists before creating it

```vb
If File.Exists(filename) Then
    oBook = oExcel.workbooks.open(filename)
Else
    oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add
End If
```

and an alternative to the Do.. While Loop would be

```vb
index = oSheet.usedrange.rows.count + 1
```

Comment: Perhaps I have inserted this code into the wrong place, but when I try to save this new data it still asks if I want to save a new copy of "spreadsheet" and get rid of the old one. I put the If loop after the 9th line of code and completely replaced the Do While loop with this new index but the data is still only saving to the second row. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lady Is the filename "spreadsheet" or does it have an extension like "spreadsheet.xlsx" ?

Comment: I removed the extension ".xlsx" because after I closed the program and saved the data to the cells I couldn't open the excel file

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line:

```
oBook = oExcel.workbooks.add
```

creates a new, blank, workbook.  `oSheet` is also blank.  There is no previous data. in the sheet; so the code always fills in from row #2

Comment: ah, okay. That makes sense - this is my first time working with a spreadsheet in vb and im already a really bad coder lmao